# Search Through Specific Set of Lines and Output Data?

Tags: vb.net

I've been struggling with this for a while now, and after extensive searching, I still have yet to find an answer.

In my Visual Basic class, I have a program where I have to get text from a text file (songs.txt), display the genres in a list box, and display corresponding songs in a combo box after a genre is displayed.

Currently, this is my code.

```
' Variables
    Dim strFilePath As String = "E:\Advanced VB\DJPlayList\DJPlayList\songs.txt"
    Dim strFileError As String = "File not found. Please try again."
    Dim strFileErrorTitle As String = "File Error"
    Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim strSongGenre(intCount) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    ' Finding the file
    If IO.File.Exists(strFilePath) Then
        ' Opening the text file
        objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strFilePath)
        Do Until objReader.Peek = -1
            ReDim Preserve strSongGenre(intCount)
            strSongGenre(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine
            cboMusicGenre.Items.Add(strSongGenre(intCount))
            intCount += 1
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox(strFileError, , strFileErrorTitle)
        Close()
    End If
```

This adds all the information from the text file into the array and loads it to the listbox, but I'm stuck at how to output the genre's specifically and the corresponding songs with it.

The text file looks as follows:

```
All You Need is Love-Beatles 'Song Name
Rock 'Song Genre
4.25 'Song Time
What Hurts the Most-Rascal Flatts
Country
5.25
Touch it-Busta Rhymes
Rap
5.46
My Girl-Temptations
R&B
4.35
What you know?-T.I.
Rap
4.30
```

How do I specifically get the genre's and the song titles? Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: This is not VBA, it's VB.NET. I've changed the tags for you... If you want help you need to make sure you address the correct audience. No one using VBA can help you with this.

Comment: @Heinzi But in this scenario, reading lines individually suits what is needed

Comment: @DavidWilson: Point taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is actually happening is that your code is reading every line and storing them all in your ComboBox.

Probably the easiest thing to do at this level would be to create 2 extra temporary string variables and instead of reading 1 line for each iteration of the loop, read the three lines that are related to each other like this

```
    tempName= objReader.ReadLine
    strSongGenre(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine
    tempDuration = objReader.ReadLine
```

If you don't want to use the Name and Duration of the song then do nothing with them and they'll be overwritten on the next iteration of the loop

So your final code should look like this

```
Do Until objReader.Peek = -1
    Dim tempName,tempDuration as string
    ReDim Preserve strSongGenre(intCount)
    tempName= objReader.ReadLine
    strSongGenre(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine
    tempDuration = objReader.ReadLine
    cboMusicGenre.Items.Add(strSongGenre(intCount))
    intCount += 1
Loop
```

Comment: @SDC That should get you going on the initial bit - Though for the other things about clicking on comboboxes to list all the songs - The above code would be re-written better. Do you know about structures? and lists (of..)? The data would be much easier to manipulate using those instead of arrays, as arrays are quite limited compared to lists and collections etc. Let me know at my email address in my profile.